# My cycles settings have disapeared

Tags: cycles-render-engine

for what i understand my cycles settings should be at the bottom of objects menu , 
but it´s no where to wound, i have cycles set as renderer, what could be the cause of this .
I have looked it ewerywhere but don´t findt it [image: where is it]

Comment: Make sure to select any mesh object first. Probably *Cycles settings* rollout isn't displayed as you have camera as active for example

Answer (score 4):

As @Mr Zak suggests in the comments, the `Cycles Settings` panel does not show in the object properties menu if the active object is a **Camera**, **Empty Object**, **Lattice** or **Forcefield**; regardless of how many objects you have selected.

Although it is not 100% clear from your screenshot which object is the active object, it appears that you have several `Empty`'s in your scene which may be the culprit, if not the camera.